# Fill in text in adjacent blank variables till another text appears in R

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to paste texts over fill in empty variables till another text appears. I want to do this for a specific row

Current table:

| var1 | var2 | var3 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | textA |  | textB |  |
| B | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| c | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

Desired output:

| var1 | var2 | var3 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | textA | textA | textB | textB |
| B | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| c | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

What's an elegant way to do this? My current solution looks something like this but I'd like to use a logic instead of specifying a variable name like below:

```
mutate(var3=case_when(var1=="A" & is.na(var3) ~ var2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may extract the row where 'var1' is "A", `unlist` and apply `na.locf0` from `zoo` to replace the NA values with the previous non-NA value

```
library(zoo)
i1 <- df1$var1 == "A"
df1[i1,-1] <-  na.locf0(unlist(df1[i1,-1]))
```

-output

```
 df1
  var1  var2  var3 var3.1  var4
1    A textA textA  textB textB
2    B     1     2      3     4
3    c     3     4      5     6
```

---

Or with `base R`, create a numeric index based on the non-NA element (`cumsum`) and use the index to replicate the non-NA values from the extracted row

```
v1 <- unlist(df1[i1, -1])
df1[i1, -1] <- na.omit(v1)[cumsum(!is.na(v1))]
```

---

Or use `tidyverse`, to reshape to 'long' format (`pivot_longer`), apply `fill` to replace NA with previous non-NA and reshape back to wide with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -var1, values_transform = as.character) %>% 
   fill(value) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  var1  var2  var3  var3.1 var4 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 A     textA textA textB  textB
2 B     1     2     3      4    
3 c     3     4     5      6
```

If there are only alternate NAs, an option is also

```
library(dplyover)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across2(c(3, 5), c(2, 4), 
   ~ case_match(.x, NA ~ .y, .default = as.character(.x)),
    .names = "{xcol}"))
```

-output

```
  var1  var2  var3 var3.1  var4
1    A textA textA  textB textB
2    B     1     2      3     4
3    c     3     4      5     6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(var1 = c("A", "B", "c"), var2 = c("textA", "1", 
"3"), var3 = c(NA, 2L, 4L), var3.1 = c("textB", "3", "5"), var4 = c(NA, 
4L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Interestingly there is no equivalent for lag or lead for horizontal use?!

Comment: @TarJae you may use `rowwise` with `c_across` and `na.locf`, but `fill` works only on columns

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option, but only for a few columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(var3 = ifelse(var3=="", var2, var3),
         var4 = ifelse(var4=="", var3.1, var4))
```

```
  var1  var2  var3  var3.1 var4 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 A     textA textA textB  textB
2 B     1     2     3      4    
3 c     3     4     5      6
```